# Order of authors in the paper, Elsevier

Tags: journals, paper-submission, elsevier

I wrote a paper, and my supervisor is the corresponding author of the paper, but in the PDF of the manuscript the order of authors is different (not the text we wrote as the paper, the first page of the manuscript which is downloadable).  I am the second and my name listed after my supervisor's name. Also, I am listed as **co_author**.
How is the situation?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you listed twice?

Comment: No in the pdf we uploaded im listed first, but in my profile my supervisor's name listed first.  I dont know its because he is corresponding auther or really he listed him self first in the submission process ( not in the pdf)

Comment: What you write is confusing, “Im and listed after...” is not clear. Should be I’m for a start.

Comment: Possibly they take first and corresponding author to be the same. Forget, it it was fine that the supervisor is the corresponding author then all is all right.

Comment: Is this perhaps a journal in field with alphabetical ordering of authors (pure math, theoretical computer science)?

Answer (score -1):

If you're unsure, you can double check with the editor, they should be able to clear it up quickly. Mistakes do happen with the names though, in one of my submissions, the editor switched the order of my first and last name. I wouldn't assume that your supervisor did this intentionally, just check with the editor (and then with your supervisor, depending on what the editor says).

Comment: I'd say check first with the advisor and then with the editor. If the advisor changed the order (for whatever reason) asking the editor is a little awkward.

Comment: Dissgree with it being awkward. If the advisor did change author without discussing with other authors then that is unethical. The editor can give definitive answer whereas an unethical advisor may twist the truth to exploit a student. Not saying its the case but I also know there's plenty of people like that.